# Ranking system using mysqli

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, system, ranking

I want to check if the user what rank a user has, which is stored in my database as an integer of 0, 1, 2, or 3.

I want it to be echo'd like echo $my_rank; #Instead of it saying 0,1,2,or 3 it says User for 0, Moderator for 1, Admin for 2, and Owner for 3.

Here is my code:

```
$my_rank = $_SESSION['rank'] = array("owner","administrator","moderator","user");

$rank = array (
    '0' => 'user',
    '1' => 'moderator',
    '2' => 'administrator',
    '3' => 'owner'
);
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

# Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

# No Error Reporting
//error_reporting(0);

# Message Responses
$success = array();
$danger = array();
$warning = array();
$info = array();

# Define the Database
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','blah');
define('DB_PASSWORD','blah');
define('DB_DATABASE','blah');

# Connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (!$con) {
    $danger[] = mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    //echo "It worked";
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you store user data? Where does INT 0,1,2 or 3 stored?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e915d49f10bdefec2a5b0b91f906ea33

Comment: Could you show more of the database structure? That image doesn't show us a lot, other than the fact you have a rank column.

Comment: Also heres what I have it set as https://gyazo.com/5e06dec0929baf87443b1b6de779e37f

Comment: Here https://gyazo.com/4b7ec7dcae8ca68932f97fab0c75ee11

Comment: What is the table's name? And have you tried to do any SQL statements on your data?

Comment: Tables name is users and I don't know.

Comment: You don't know if you've tried to query your data?

Comment: Username, Email & Password are but not my Rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can query the database with sql statements. The one you're looking for is a select upon the usertable:

```
// array which holds the info
$rank = array ('user', 'moderator', 'administrator', 'owner');
// set up db connection
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (!$con) {
    $danger[] = mysqli_connect_error();
} else { 
    //echo "It worked";

    // Baklap4's Addition:

    // SQL statement to retrieve the row where username is piet
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = `piet`";

    // Execute the query and check if there is a result.
    if ($result = $con->query($sql)) { 
        // if there are results loop through them.
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            // print for each rank a different rank name.
            echo $rank[$row['rank']];
        } 
        // free resultset
        $result->close();
    } 
    // close connection
    $con->close();
    //clean up the temp variables 
    unset($obj); 
    unset($sql); 
    unset($result);
}
```

This will retrieve The user `Piet` from your database and print the rank (which is listed in the database).
Then it'll unset all the temporary values made within the whileloop so you can't reuse them again.

What you should do is change the hard coded value `piet` to a variable. One could go to `http://localhost/scriptname.php?username=piet` to retrieve the same outcome.

To make this a variable change the sql line as following:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = $_GET['username']";`

Comment: I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Elaborate what you're confused about. We can't help unless we know what to help with.

Comment: All I'm trying to get it to do is detect whether the INT in the rank row = 0,1,2, or 3 and if it does I want it to respond back with like 2 = Admin(But only have it say admin)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\config.php on line 25

Comment: Another error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\config.php:48 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\config.php on line 48`

Comment: Should be running fine now

Comment: Works now! Thank you!

Comment: try it again, does it still keeps on loading?

Comment: I have to recode some stuff to get it fixed but thank you for it, it works!

Comment: if it works please mark your selected answer so others can find the answer too

Answer (score 1):

Well... Going by the information you've given me, it seems like all that is needed is a query, to get the data from the database. Then we can echo it.

In the `else` block in your database connection, we can do something like:

```
# Connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (!$con) {
    $danger[] = mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    //echo "It worked";

    // HopefulLlama code below:

    // Construct our SQL query, which will retrieve data from the database.
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Users";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    // Loop through all results return by our query
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // $row['rank'] will contain our Integer of 0, 1, 2, or 3
        echo $row['rank']

        // This will access your $rank array, and use the index retrieved from the database as an accessor.
        echo $rank[$row['rank']]
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this any different then my answer?

Comment: It's not, you just got your answer in while I was typing mine.

Comment: @Baklap4 this answer is way more clear and less confusing. And it does answer the question.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: rank in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\config.php on line 39

Comment: Did you leave out the quotes? `rank` shouldn't be a variable, we're accessing the array through associative names, so it should be quoted as `'rank'`

Comment: @KameronSchwab you have to make your mind in which variable your ranks are stored. You **have** $rank variable in your question but now you says it is undefined. Where did it go? May be $_SESSION['rank'] will do.